# Why do I get "no method 'indexOf'" error when trying to use a Buffered Renderer on a grid in ExtJS4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm tying to set up a Buffered Renderer for a grid, I have a store and a grid set up similar to the following:

```
var ds = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "TestStore",
    data: myData,
    pageSize: 100,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'array',
            useSimpleAccessors: true
        }
    }
});

var grid = Ext.widget({
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: ds,
    // ... More setup
    autoLoad: true,
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'bufferedrenderer'
    }
})
```

When I try to load this grid in my program however, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'indexOf'
```

On this line:

```
urlAppend : function(url, string) {
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(string)) {
            return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + string;
        }

        return url;
    },
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Ext.String.urlAppend 
Ext.apply.urlAppend 
Ext.define.setOptions 
Ext.define.request 
Ext.define.load 
Ext.define.constructor 
constructor 
Ext.define.getLoader 
Ext.define.constructor 
Base.implement.callParent 
Ext.define.constructor 
constructor 
Ext.apply.widget
```

I've followed the setup the way the documentation suggests [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer), but I can't find anything about what I'm doing wrong either on their official docs, or through other sites after some googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use autoLoad on the grid.
The correct place to use it, should be the underlying data store.

Comment: Ah, a simple oversight on my behalf. Thanks.